# fingerprint in logstash filter option not working properly?

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, logstash, fingerprint, elk

I have used below code but its only inserting one record to ES .

```
filter {
  fingerprint {
    target => "document_id"
    method => "SHA256"
    key => "9ced3827c6a1c9dafac6da9abac41386ba1038ac95b3a865a0951bc2e948c58c"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => localhost
    document_id => "%{document_id}"
  }
}
```

Please point out the mistake below I have approx 200k records in my sql which i am importing to ES. I want unique ids for each record using this fingerprint.

Comment: Please don't use Indian words like "lac" here. There's people also from other places and they aren't going to understand you.

Comment: @AnjaliKushwaha just for your information, you can't ping/tag other users on SO, unlike on other websites

Answer (score 1):

This is working logstash configuration which gives the fingerprint. As document_id is existing field in output section change to something else.

```
filter {
  fingerprint {
    target => "fingerprint"
    method => "SHA256"
    key => "9ced3827c6a1c9dafac6da9abac41386ba1038ac95b3a865a0951bc2e948c58c"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => localhost
    document_id => "%{fingerprint}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Default source of the [fingerprint filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-fingerprint.html#plugins-filters-fingerprint-source) is the `message` field. Are you sure you have such field?